# Pandas rank vs transform('rank')

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but I really want to understand how it works.

I have a very simple dataset

```
In [0]: data
Out[0]:
  group  value  data
0     A      1     1
1     A      2     1
2     B      3     1
3     B      4     1
```

And then I have some transformations:

```
In [1]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank')
Out[1]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.5
1    2.0   1.5
2    1.0   1.5
3    2.0   1.5

In [2]: data.groupby('group').value.transform('rank')
Out[2]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2

In [3]: data.groupby('group').data.transform('rank')
Out[3]:
0    1.5
1    1.5
2    1.5
3    1.5

In [4]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank').value
Out[4]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0

In [5]: data.groupby('group').value.rank()
Out[5]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0

In [6]: data.groupby('group').cumcount()
Out[6]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
```

The things I find strange:

- The 1st one. While I seem to understand what happened to `value` column (similar to the 5th and 6th ones) I can't understand what happened to `data` column. Where did the value `1.5` come from?
- The 2nd one. Instead of selecting only specified column and applying logic similar to the 1st one it completely changed the output. I can presume that now in enumerates groups instead of rows inside of groups, but I still don't understand why it's done in such a strange way?
- The 3rd one. It behaves exactly as expected in terms that it just selected specified column and applied the same logic from the 1st one (in contrast to previous one). But I'm still missing the origin of this value;
- The 4th one. Shouldn't this one be the same as the 2nd one?
- The 5th and 6th ones looks exactly the same, but the latter one starts from 0. Is it correct?

I would very appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add bit more confusion - [rank()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method has a `method` parameter ...

default: `method='average'`

```
In [70]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank')
Out[70]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.5
1    2.0   1.5
2    1.0   1.5
3    2.0   1.5

In [71]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank', method='average')
Out[71]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.5
1    2.0   1.5
2    1.0   1.5
3    2.0   1.5
```

method: `min`

```
In [72]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank', method='min')
Out[72]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.0
1    2.0   1.0
2    1.0   1.0
3    2.0   1.0
```

method: `max`

```
In [73]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank', method='max')
Out[73]:
   value  data
0    1.0   2.0
1    2.0   2.0
2    1.0   2.0
3    2.0   2.0
```

method: `first`

```
In [74]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank', method='first')
Out[74]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.0
1    2.0   2.0
2    1.0   1.0
3    2.0   2.0
```

method: `dense`

```
In [75]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank', method='dense')
Out[75]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.0
1    2.0   1.0
2    1.0   1.0
3    2.0   1.0
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

> **method** : {`average`, `min`, `max`, `first`, `dense`}
>
> average: average rank of group
>
> min: lowest rank in group
>
> max: highest rank in group
>
> first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
>
> dense: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups

and there is yet another parameter:

> **pct** : boolean, default False
>
> Computes percentage rank of data

Comment: That definitely makes things even more confusing to me. But I still don't understand two things: 1) How `1.5` is calculated for `data` column? How can be average for 1 and 1 be 1.5? 2) Why it seems like a different logic as applied to `value` and `data` columns?

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of pandas (mine is 0.24.2), `data.groupby('group').transform('rank')` and `data.groupby('group').value.transform('rank')` behave as below:

```
In [1]: data.groupby('group').transform('rank')
Out[1]:
   value  data
0    1.0   1.5
1    1.0   1.5
2    2.0   1.5
3    2.0   1.5

In [2]: data.groupby('group').value.transform('rank')
Out[2]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
```

To answer your question:

- the 1st and 3rd: Default `method` of `rank()` func is `average`, therefore, data column gets rank 1.5 (min=1, max=2, average=1.5)
- the 2nd and 4th: In later version of pandas, `data.groupby('group').transform('rank').value` returns the same as `data.groupby('group').value.transform('rank')`. I would suggest do not use `transform()` and `rank()` together, **`data.groupby('group').value.rank()` is exactly what you should use**. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2078) of `rank()` function. It already implements the logic of `transform()`: broadcast to the entire column. If you end up using `transform('rank')`, the `rank` func still does its job, but `transform` messes up. Here's a simplified version of what the source code does:

  ```py
  import pandas as pd
  import pandas.core.algorithms as algorithms

  g = data.groupby('group')
  result = getattr(g, 'rank')() #same as g.rank()
  ids = g.grouper.group_info[0] #array([0, 0, 1, 1])

  output = []
  for i, _ in enumerate(result.columns):
      res = algorithms.take_1d(result.iloc[:, i].values, ids)
      output.append(res) 
      #[array([1., 1., 2., 2.]), array([1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5])]
  pd.DataFrame._from_arrays(output, columns=result.columns, index=g.obj.index)
  #value|data
  #  1  | 1.5
  #  1  | 1.5
  #  2  | 1.5
  #  2  | 1.5
  ```
- the 5th and 6th: `cumcount()` starts from 0 to the length of that group - 1, `rank()` starts from 1 to n.

Hope this helps.